# calling Activities from Geofence in android

Tags: android, android-geofence

I wish to bring Activities to the foreground directly when entering/exiting a geofenced area.

I have 5 geofenced areas and wish to bring ActivityA to the foreground when I'm entering Geofence area A (specified in Lat/Long), Activity B when I'm at geofence are B and so on. (It's a non-consumer app, so I don't mind invoking Activities directly from the service to the foreground.)

I've read [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) on Geofencing in Android. How do I call different Activities when they receive the different IDs of the geofenced areas?

The pending intents:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...

    private PendingIntent getTransitionPendingIntent() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,
                ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);

        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

...
}
```

And the Handler Intent:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {

        int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);

        Log.e("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService",
                "Location Services error: " +
                Integer.toString(errorCode));

    } else {
        // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
        int transitionType =
                LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
        // Test that a valid transition was reported
        if (
            (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
             ||
            (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
           ) {
            List <Geofence> triggerList =
                    getTriggeringGeofences(intent);

            String[] triggerIds = new String[geofenceList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < triggerIds.length; i++) {
                // Store the Id of each geofence
                triggerIds[i] = triggerList.get(i).getRequestId();
            }

        }

    } else {
        Log.e("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService",
                "Geofence transition error: " +
                Integer.toString()transitionType));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) states that you shouldn't do this:

> The Intent sent from Location Services can trigger various actions in your app, but you should not have it start an activity or fragment, because components should only become visible in response to a user action. In many cases, an IntentService is a good way to handle the intent.

Comment: He is using an intent service